# How can I get the value of an object inside an array based on a variable in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am working on a nested js application that is attempting to create a clean json schema - from more raw data.

So as I loop through the data - I want to pick up the label value which is nested like this.

```
label: data[x]["title"]["values"]["en"]
```

I want to create in the parent a pointer - to this data so

```
parentLabelPointer : "title.values.en"
```

---

but I can not simply do a get of this variable (using ember) like this

```
label: data[x][this.get("parentLabelPointer")]
```

if it was just one level - this would work. e.b. "parentLabelPointer : "title""

is there a clean way to pick this data up -- without having to try and drill down to the data in nested arrays like `["title"]["values"]["en"]`?

this is so I can make the module more modular -- if its to work with different data sets and different nesting levels.

---

my example

```
  getLabel: function(prefix, pointer){
    var trail = pointer.split(".");

    var label = prefix;
    trail.forEach(function(element) {
      label = label[element];
    });

    return label;
  }
```

usage

```
this.getLabel(data[x], this.get('parentLabelPointer'))
```

data[x] is like the known level of the branch -- but to find the label in the raw data --

parentLabelPointer - is like "title.values.en"

Comment: have you tried `this.get('title.values.en')`?

Comment: that would mean setting the key as "title.values.en" ... -- its really handing down the structure from the parent - to its inner component.

Comment: data[x].title.values.en -- would be valid -- but its like at this level I got data[x] -- now need to trail through either a split "." string to get to the value in "en"

Comment: Ah ok, I think more code would be beneficial. I didn't know these were coming from different components. I think I have an idea though

Comment: FYI, I see no JSON in this at all. I'm guessing by JSON you mean a Javascript object, JSON is a string notation

Comment: I don't understand the edit you've made, is that your answer to the problem?

Comment: parentLabelPointer : "title.values.en"  - is a json object -- and is the value "title.values.en"

Comment: Ok, none of this makes sense. Please try and explain your problem more clearly. Preferably with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. Until you do that no one is going to be able to help

Comment: I've fixed it already

Comment: sigh, well that was a waste of everyone's time...

Comment: well no -- I did explain the issue - but its just wasn't understood as well

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
...

label:computed('parentLabelPointer', 'data.[]', 'x', function(){
    let x = this.get('x');
    let data = this.get('data');
    let parentLabelPointer = this.get('parentLabelPointer');
    return data[x].get(parentLabelPointer);

}
```

That all said it's pretty unclear what `x`, `data`, etc is or how they're supposed to work, etc. This does feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: getLabel: function(prefix, pointer){

    var trail = pointer.split(".");
    console.log("trail", trail);
    console.log("prefix", prefix);

    var label = prefix;

    trail.forEach(function(element) {
      label = label[element];
      console.log("label", label);
    });


    console.log("label", label);
    return label;

  },

Comment: its not possible in a comment box

Comment: Just, if you've tried this answer, and it didn't meet your expectations, if you could talk about that, it would be helpful

Comment: This isn't correct in terms of the data structure - or what this.get('parentLabelPointer') - would actually be

Comment: *That all said it's pretty unclear what x, data, etc is or how they're supposed to work*

Comment: data[x] - represents an object.. so exploring it further from its origin branch